# Cannot Connect To siebel From Dot net application After siebel 8.2.2.4.17 Update

Tags: vb.net, siebel

We Have 2 solutions
one is siebel application and the other is dotnet application connected to siebel application which read many things from the siebel application and connect to its BC to do the insert, update ,delete , etc operations
we use Siebel COM Data Control to connect to sibel from dotnet application
Everything was working well till the siebel team upgrade to siebel 8.2.2.4.17
Then the Dot Net Application stopped and cannot connect to siebel application anymore

Answer (score 0):

For such issues it is best to raise an SR with Oracle. You will need the Siebel side logs to debug the issue.